# Error: could not write config file ,Resource temporarily unavailable and warning: unable to unlink

Tags: git, macos, gradle, build.gradle, .git-folder

Git issues when cloning any repo. Resource unavailable and when trying to check out new branch every file contains warning of : unable to unlink.

Searched for solution and couldn't find anything with this exact issue.

My git version is:

```
git version 2.15.2 (Apple Git-101.1)
```

The errors and warnings received when cloning a repo below.

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: Counting objects: 11812, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4191/4191), done.
remote: Total 11812 (delta 4965), reused 10164 (delta 4474)
Receiving objects: 100% (11812/11812), 3.21 MiB | 1.18 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4965/4965), done.
warning: unable to unlink '/Users/myusername/Workspace/repo/.git/config.lock': Resource temporarily unavailable
error: could not write config file /Users/myusername/Workspace/repo/.git/config: Resource temporarily unavailable
warning: unable to unlink '/Users/myusername/Workspace/repo/.git/objects/pack/pack- 
44eb34891f78eafbe39cee406ff6c4d694465be4.keep': Resource temporarily 
unavailable
```

Assuming this is something related to permissions however I have write permissions on .git also experiencing a similar issue on gradle as I build projects.

```
Following error:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.58/module-metadata.bin (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Hoping someone may have experienced something similar and a possible solution.

Comment: Also seeing this issue on OSX High Sierra, on same version (git version 2.15.2 (Apple Git-101.1)) and also git version 2.18.0

Comment: I have the same issues on OSX High Sierra (10.13.6) and early-2015 and mid-2014 Macbook Pro laptops. I also experience file write errors in IDEA IntelliJ on the same laptops. It looks to me like filesystem got corrupted due to software or hardware issues.